# ¿Buscar archivos html con keyword en su interior?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css3

Bueno les cuento, tengo una web donde tengo productos a la venta. Anteriormente podía ponerlos en la pagina principal sin preocuparme que los clientes no hallaran lo que buscaban porque eran pocos productos. Pero ahora he incrementado el catálogo y empiezo a requerir un método de búsqueda que encuentra cada producto.
No quiero usar un **CMS** y tampoco quiero re diseñar mi web desde cero con **Bases de Datos**.
Tenia pensado hacer un **Search Box** que buscara **Keywords** con los datos pertinentes para la búsqueda.

Por ejemplo: Tengo un producto a la venta, digamos un **Auto** de color **rojo**
entonces tengo un archivo `autorojo.html` donde esta toda la info sobre el auto.
(Si, estoy perfectamente enterado que no es la mejor forma de hacer una pagina, es preferible usar Bases de datos, y hacer todo con PHP, pero mis conocimientos no dan para tanto por ahora. así que espero que respeten por ahora mi manera de hacer las cosas)

Ahora: digamos que tengo, en el archivo `autorojo.html` y dentro, en el `<head>`
tengo una etiqueta `<meta>` de la siguiente manera: `<meta name="keywords" content="auto, rojo">`
Me gustaria saber si hay alguna manera con PHP o JS de, mediante un **Search Box** de buscar las Keywords presentes en el archivo HTML y hacer hacer una llamada a ese archivo para luego hacer un display en la parte de la web pertinente.

Se que a algunos les parecerá un poco obsoleto pero planeo aprender PHP a fondo y usar **MVC** en un futuro cercano para re diseñar la pagina.

Aceptare sugerencias de otros métodos de diseño, si creen que el mio no tiene remedio jaja.

Muchisimas gracias de antemano!

Comment: La verdad no tiene remedio... pero es sencillo hacer lo que quieres, buscaras dentro del html que contiene los meta asi: 

`string ItemToSearch; htmlString.split("keywords").forEach(myFunction) function myFunction(item, index) { string itemFound = htmlString[index + 11]; if (itemFound.Contains(ItemToSearch)) <form action="$(itemFound + .html)"><input type="submit">$itemFound</form> }`

Aunque no he tirado codigo en Javascript esto debe jugar.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta las limitaciones que planteas, creo que lo mejor que podrias hacer es integrar el buscador de Google en tu sitio (https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630969?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia es la siguiente:

Hacer algo que busque en otros archivos con las limitaciones expresadas seria un dolor de cabeza. También supongo que tienes un volumen moderado y que vas agregando los productos a mano.

En estas circunstancias lo más fácil es que dentro de la página de inicio en la que tienes el buscador pongas, ya sea de manera visible o no, un indice de tus productos con su url y sus etiquetas.

Luego con Jquery buscas dentro de ese mismo indice en ese mismo archivo, lo que es mucho mas fácil de hacer.

Puedes usar data para lograrlo fácilmente:

```
<a href="LaURLdeTuProducto" data-etiquetas='["a","b","c"]'>Mi Producto</a>
<a href="LaURLdeTuProducto2" data-etiquetas='["x","y","z"]'>Mi Producto2</a>
```

Luego recuperas las etiquetas de cada elemento así:

```
  var etiquetas = $('a').data('etiquetas');
```

Y puedes usar .each() para hacer un ciclo que pase por todos los elementos y hacer allí algún criterio de búsqueda.

No es ni lo más eficiente ni lo más técnicamente adecuado, peor creo que resuelve con las limitaciones que pides.